# How to make a mutation for graphql that had a relation in schema

Tags: postgresql, go, graphql

I have a schema.graphqls like this :

```
type User {
    id:ID!
    name:String!
    username:String!
    email:String!
    password:String!
    posts: [Post]  
}

type Post{
    id:ID!
    caption:String!
    userid:Int!
}
```

I connect this with a postgre sql database like below:
[image]

My question is how to make a mutation for create new user???

I tried to do this on graphql playground:

```
  createUser(input:{
    name:"Logan Giqualen"
    username:"logichekit"
    email:"logangiqualen@ymail.com"
    password:"123123"
  })
  {
    name
  }
}
```

And this is my schema.resolvers.go :

```
func (r *mutationResolver) CreateUser(ctx context.Context, input model.NewUser) (*model.User, error) {
    // hash, _ := HashPassword(input.Password)
    var posts []*model.Post
    user := model.User{
        Name:     input.Name,
        Username: input.Username,
        Email:    input.Email,
        Password: input.Password,
        Posts:    posts,
    }

    _, err := r.DB.Model(&user).Insert()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("insert new user error")
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

But is give an internal server error in graphql playground.

Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Does the server itself log errors anywhere? You need to find out what the internal error was.

Comment: @loganfsmyth , The error said this : 

"errors": [
    {
      "message": "ERROR #42703 column \"posts\" of relation \"users\" does not exist",